# Attach an object to already attached object

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to know if it is possible to attach an object to an already attached object to the robot.

I tried to attach a second object to the first object (already attached to the robot) but got the error `Link 'first_object' not found in model 'robot'`

I attached the second object as a planning scene diff with these details :

`attached_object.link_name = "first_object";` `planning_scene.robot_state.attached_collision_objects.push_back(attached_object)` `planning_scene.robot_state.is_diff = true;`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250036/attach-an-object-to-already-attached-object/) by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2016-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Like you already guessed, that is not possible. The error `Link 'first_object' not found in model 'robot'` is coming from the [robot_model.cpp](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/e97038d476c4e45817e80f6ec5e58d5840ccf004/moveit_core/robot_model/src/robot_model.cpp#L1115). The planning scene updater looks for a LinkModel to attach the object to but cannot find it.

However, if you attach to the link of the robot that the first object is attached to, you will get the exact same result. As the transform between the `Link` and `first_object` will be static, and between `Link` and `second_object` as well (once you attach them), the transform between `first_object` and `second_object` will also be static.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on 2016-12-14**:
I thought of that method but the problem in my case is that I have a host of objects of different sizes that I have to attach. So attaching them to the `link` the `first_object` was attached to works for some but not all (The others get displaced from where they are supposed to be).

**Comment by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on 2016-12-14**:
Can I attach the `second_object` to the `link` but assign the `TF` of the `first_object` ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-14**:\

> The others get displaced from where they are supposed to be

that would seem to imply that your objects either have their origins not where they should be, of you're not accounting for the additional offset that you need to include between `Link` and your new objects.

**Comment by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on 2016-12-19**:
Yes, I had manually shifted the origin of the `second_object` so that they would be oriented properly when attached to the `link`. But after reading your comment, I got another idea of how to do it. So I set the origins at the right places and set up some parameters and now it works fine. Thank you!